# How to point to a folder relative to Python file when running in virtualenv/Pipenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

*I don't think my question is FastAPI-specific, but more Python-virtualenv generic, but here's my example use case with FastAPI anyway.*

I'm running FastAPI from a virtualenv set up by Pipenv and I'd like it to serve static files for development purposes only. I know this is solved with a proper production deployment and I will be using a proper web server for that, but my question below is about the development environment.

File structure looks like this:

```
├── frontend          <-- frontend code dir
│   ├── dist          <-- frontend build output (static files)
│   ├── public
│   └── [..]
├── Pipfile           <-- contains 'myproject = {editable = true, path = "."}' as dep
├── Pipfile.lock
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── myproject         <-- backend code dir
│   ├── web.py        <-- fastapi file
│   └── [...]
└── [...]
```

`myproject/web.py`:

```py
import fastapi

app = fastapi.FastAPI()
app.mount("/", fastapi.staticfiles.StaticFiles(
    directory="/absolute/path/to/frontend/dist"),
    name="static",
)
```

Running the FastAPI dev server with `pipenv run uvicorn myproject.web:app --reload`.

Which works now, but I'd like to avoid this *absolute path* in my public source. Any relative path does not work, as it appears to be relative to the installed path in the virtualenv created by Pipenv, which is not deterministic. The same goes for the `__file__` path; it's inside a virtualenv.

I've also considered to add the statics as data files to the Python package and load it from the directory as provided by `pkg_resources` (e.g. `pkg_resources.resource_filename('myproject', 'data/')`), but I don't plan to ship the statics with the Python package in production so it feels hackish.

Would it be possible to somehow link the right directory here by a relative path or do you have another clever idea in order to share the project in a team of devs (or publicly on GitHub for that matter) a little bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to be flexible from where it will run and the statics location is unrelated, any constant relative path can not work.

I would go for:

1. Discovering the statics by some heuristics like walking back to the some known "anchor" folder (root folder?)

I've done something like this once, and even cached the found absolute path result in some persistent temp file so this discovery will happen only once per machine (unless the location moved or the temp cached file was deleted).

2. Setting the static location as config/command-line/both parameter that your server launched with.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good idea, I could look at adding a custom command line option, e.g. `pipenv run uvicorn myproject.web:app --reload --static-dir="$(pwd)/frontend/dist"`

Comment: well if you can build on `pwd` it is easier as `os.getcwd' will give it to you from the code

Comment: Yes, although it restricts me from running pipenv from a subdirectory. But that's okay for my web serving use case, I guess. Thanks.